# What is the difference of .string() and .toString() for OkHttp?

Tags: java, android, okhttp, tostring

I'm new to OkHttp library.
While working with this library I was downloading source of a web page.
Here is my code:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(urls[0])
                    .build();
try {
    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    source = response.body().toString();
    Log.i("ppp",source);
} catch (IOException e) {
    source =e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But is was showing me this response :

```
07-27 11:55:39.133 28050-28069/com.portonics.didar.okhttpdemo I/ppp: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@420b639
```

But later just by changing .toString() with .string() is shows correct result .

```
07-27 11:59:29.451 28050-31483/com.portonics.didar.okhttpdemo I/ppp: <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){window.google={kEI:'JIF5WcLwC8Sd0gT1w6HIAQ',kEXPI:'1301798,1352823,1353383,1353801,1354231,1354277,1354562,1354570,1354619,1354625,1354838,3700277,3700347,3700433,3700442,4029815,4031109,4040138,4043492,4045840,4048347,4063220,4072777,4076999,4078430,4081038,4081164,4093313,4094544,4095910,4096463,4097153,4097922,4097929,4097951,4098721,4098728,4098752,4099391,4102237,4103475,4103845,4103861,4104258,4104658,4105085,4105113,4105241,4106626,4107555,4108124,4108498,4109316,4109490,4110259,4110404,4110656,4111016,4112542,4113148,4113216,4113495,4114597,4114975,4115697,4116365,4116926,4116935,4117280,4117406,4117534,4117912,4117980,4118103,4118227,4118280,4118475,4118626,4118798,4118976,4118977,4119032,4119034,4119036,4119272,4120004,4120046,4120058,4120195,4120278,4120289,4120508,4120578,4120646,4121035,4121036,4121209,4121278,4121316,4121515,4121852,4122007,4122048,4122705,4122724,4123335,4123994,4124100,4124288,10200083,10200096,16200027',authuser:0,kscs:'c9c918f0_24'};google.kHL='en';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.wl=function(a,b){try{google.ml(Error(a),!1,b)}catch(c){}};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,c,d,g){if(a=google.logUrl(a,b,c,d,g)){b=new Image;var e=google.lc,f=google.li;e[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete e[f]};google.vel&&google.vel.lu&&google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,c,d,g){var e="",f=google.ls||"";c||-1!=b.search("&ei=")||(e="&ei="+google.getEI(d),-1==b.search("&lei=")&&(d=google.getLEI(d))&&(e+="&lei="+d));a=c||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+e+f+"&zx="+google.time();/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a};google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){if(a)var c=a.id;else{do c=Math.random();while(google.y[c])}google.y[c]=[a,b];return!1};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};}).call(this);google.f={};var a=window.location,b=a.href.indexOf("#");if(0<=b){var c=a.href.substring(b+1);/(^|&)q=/.test(c)&&-1==c.indexOf("#")&&a.replace("/search?"+c.replace(/(^|&)fp=[^&]*/g,"")+"&cad=h")};</script><style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}
                                                                     </style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#36c}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important
```

**string()** and **toString()** is pretty much confusing. 
Can someone please tell me why these were happening and what is the difference between this two method ?

Comment: Are you loooking for the difference in these two methods?

Comment: toString() method is written in Object class which is parent class of every class in java soo when we don't override this method java internally creates a hashcode for a object and returns it as String. But when you are calling string() method which is defined by RealResponseBody class you are getting the actual response. I hope it cleared your confusion

Comment: Unrelated: The response body must be closed. Read here https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html

Comment: Not your fault. It is very poor design on their part. They should have overridden `toString()` to do the same as `string(),` or indeed omitted `string()` altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`string()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html#string--) is a method of [`ResponseBody`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html) that, to quote the documentation:

> Returns the response as a string decoded with the charset of the Content-Type header. If that header is either absent or lacks a charset, this will attempt to decode the response body in accordance to its BOM or UTF-8.

`toString()` is inherited from `java.lang.Object` and is not overriden by `ResponseBody`, so it will return the default implementetation (something like `okhttp3.ResponseBody@{some hash code}`.

Answer (score 4):

**.toString()**    : This returns your object in string format.

**.string()**      : This returns your server response.

Answer (score 1):

.toString() : This returns your object in string format.

.string() : This returns ResponseBody which is response from server.

Answer (score 1):

```
.toString() Explanation :
```

If you want to represent any object as a string, toString() method comes into existence.

The toString() method returns the string representation of the object.

If you print any object, java compiler internally invokes the toString() method on the object. So overriding the toString() method, returns the desired output, it can be the state of an object etc. depends on your implementation.

Advantage of Java toString() method

By overriding the toString() method of the Object class, we can return values of the object, so we don't need to write much code.

```
string() Explanation :
```

In java, string is basically an object that represents sequence of char values. An array of characters works same as java string. For example:

```
char[] ch={'j','a','v','a','t','p','o','i','n','t'};  
String s=new String(ch);
```